# Difference in Milestone TargetDate value and Custom field DateTime value when passed the same date

Tags: sdk, rally, appsdk2, milestone

I am trying to save a dateTime value in my custom field in the Milestone Object Model and I see something is different between the TargetDate and my DateTime custom field:
For example I am saving `"2018-04-06T00:00:00.000Z"`to TargetDate and my custom field but on Rally side, its saved in two different format. Why would that be the case?
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why. All the dates are converted to UTC for built in fields whereas for custom fields it expects the date to be UTC. 
Converted my c_date to UTC and saved it and they matched :-)

Thanks!

Comment: Cool, glad you got it.  That seems like a weird default behavior to me- for it to behave differently between custom and built-in fields.  I think the best practice it to always specify the full date+time when setting values, which seems like where you landed.